# Необъяснимое поведение

Tags: windows, atl, mfc, c++

```
sourcePicture - объект класса CImage
cout << sourcePicture.GetPitch();             //выводит -2100
cout << sizeof(bgr);                          //выводит 3
cout << sourcePicture.GetPitch()/3;           //выводит -700
cout << sourcePicture.GetPitch()/sizeof(bgr); //выводит 14543789234
```

Какого чёрта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Следите за типами выражения.

Тип `sourcePicture.GetPitch()`, судя по всему, `signed int`. Тип константы 3 есть `int`, и судя по всему, на вашем компиляторе `int` есть `signed int`. Согласно [правилам](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), при делении `signed int` на `signed int` тип результат — тоже `signed int`.

Теперь, тип выражения `sizeof(bgr)` — `unsigned int`. При делении, согласно тем же правилам, происходит конверсия делимого к `unisigned int`. Следовательно, результат должен быть такой:

```
(unsigned int)(-2100) / (unsigned int)3 = 4294965196 / 3 = 1431655065
```

Проверьте ваш результат, вы пишете 14543789234.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! Привел sizeof к int. Тоже вроде работает. Можно же так сделать, да?

Comment: @Gar: Пожалуйста!

Да, так и надо. Приводите к `int`.

Comment: С точки зрения арифметики, конечно, верно. 

А как насчет *физического смысла* таких вычислений?